# Property 'noUiSlider' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: typescript, browserify, tsd

This is a road block. What am I doing wrong?

```
....
/// <reference path="../../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />
var slider:HTMLElement = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: +$input.val(),
    step: +$input.prop('step'),
    behaviour: 'tap',
    range: {
        'min': +$input.prop('min'),
        'max': +$input.prop('max')
    },
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,
        thousand: ','
    })
});

// this barfs in TS — error in as title of this post
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', (values, handle) => {
    $input.val(values[0]);
});

// this does too.
<HTMLElement>slider.noUiSlider.on('update', (values, handle) => {
    $input.val(values[0]);
});
```

My TSD file contains the nouislider typing from https://github.com/retyped/nouislider-tsd-ambient/blob/master/nouislider.d.ts

Error details:

```
{ [TypeScript error: resources/assets/typescript/common.ts(44,25): Error TS2339: Property 'noUiSlider' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.]
    message: 'resources/assets/typescript/common.ts(44,25): Error TS2339: Property \'noUiSlider\' does not exist on type \'HTMLElement\'.',
    fileName: 'resources/assets/typescript/common.ts',
    line: 44,
    column: 25,
    name: 'TypeScript error' }
```

Thoughts?

Edit:
My IDE (PHPStorm) is hinting that there could be an error. [image]
 That points to `lib.es6.d.ts` and of course `noUiSlider`aint going to be there.
 [image]

Edit (solution):

```
var slider = document.getElementById('slider') as noUiSlider.Instance;

    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
      //...blah...
    });

    slider.noUiSlider.on('update', (values, handle) => {
        $input.val(values[0]);
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the linked `d.ts` it seems that you need to do:

```
var slider: noUiSlider.Instance = document.getElementById('slider') as noUislider.Instance;
```

They don't seem to change the `HTMLElement` interface, instead they extend it with `noUiSlider.Instance`:

```
declare module noUiSlider {
    ...
    interface noUiSlider {
        ...
    }

    interface Instance extends HTMLElement {
        noUiSlider: noUiSlider
    }
}
```

Comment: Error TS2322: Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'Instance'. Going to update the question with some more info in a sec.

Comment: How about `var slider = document.getElementById('slider') as noUiSlider.Instance;`?

Comment: Same error message. This is weird. It's as if the typings file is just being ignored.

Comment: Actually you nailed it. It took the casting on the slider instancea, and it has resolved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Just came across this myself and looking through the file

**...\node_modules\nouislider\dist\nouislider.d.ts**


I can see the correct type as `export { TargetElement as target };`
So entering the below line resolved the type error for me

`let dragTapSlider: noUiSlider.target = document.getElementById(
        'monday'
      ) as noUiSlider.target;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution:

```js
let slider = document.getElementById('slider') as noUiSlider.target;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).